# Gulp is not running. It is giving "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" error

Tags: node.js, gulp-watch

I am getting this error after run GULP

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import gulp from 'gulp';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at requireOrImport (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/shared/require-or-import.js:19:11)
```

What did i make mistake ? I have updated the gulp, node and composer. But still i am getting the same error.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of import can you try require? Just like this

`var express = require("express");`

Please check this url for more help
https://reactgo.com/node-unexpected-token-import/